# Function that can be called on Strings and Int. Ambiguous type variable problem

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that can be called on numbers (e.g. `1`) and on strings (e.g. `"a"`). It is important in my application to simplify "user code" as much as possible.

The minimal example of my code looks like this

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

type StrInt = Either String Int


class Lift a where
  toStrInt :: a -> StrInt

instance Lift String where
  toStrInt= Left

instance Lift Int where
  toStrInt= Right

declare:: StrInt ->String
declare (Left a) = "String: " ++ a
declare (Right n) = "Number: " ++ (show n)

declare' :: Lift a => a -> String
declare' a = declare (toStrInt a)

myDecA = declare' "a"
myDec1 = declare' 1
```

Compiling this gives the error

```
 Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘declare'’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Lift a0)’ from being solved.
```

I understand the problem and I know that I can replace the last line with any of the following:

- `myDec1 = declare' (1::Int)`
- `myDec1 = declare (Right 1)`

But that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a clever way of setting the same idea such that it makes clear that 1 is an Int?

Also, In my application (more complex than the minimal example above) The `declare` function only works for `Int` s. So I can't generalize it for all `Num a`.

Comment: The problem is that `"a"` is clear (if you do not enable `OverloadedStrings`, whereas `1` can be any `Num` type). If the semantics of `Int`, `Int32`, etc. (slighlty) change, the `myDec1` can thus be different depending on the type the compiler "picks". See https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html

Comment: can you accomplish this by making your type a newtype and writing `fromInteger` and `fromString` (the latter requires `OverloadedStrings`)? It seems kinda hacky but might work.

Comment: @cole Your solution works, thanks! Clearly what I'm doing is Hacky, so I don't mind the approach. If you want to write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, this is a hacky solution. There might be a cleaner way.

But what you can do is enable `OverloadedStrings` and then make `NumStr` an instance of `IsString` and `Num` so that you can convert literals to it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Hacky where

import Data.String (IsString(..))

newtype StrInt = StrInt (Either String Int)

instance IsString StrInt where
  fromString str = StrInt (Left str)

instance Num StrInt where
  -- fromIntegral is to convert 'Integer' to 'Int'.
  fromInteger n = StrInt (Right (fromIntegral n))
  -- other methods for 'Num' are missing...

declare :: StrInt -> String
declare (StrInt (Left a))  = "String: " ++ a
declare (StrInt (Right n)) = "Number: " ++ show n

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ declare "hi"
  putStrLn $ declare 1
```

Note that I didn't implement the other required methods for `Num`, which you may wish to do, otherwise code like `declare (1 + 3)` won't typecheck.

I'd be happier with this if there was something like `OverloadedNumbers`, but I couldn't find a pragma like that.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible using Haskell. The reason for this is that while `1` *looks* like an `Int`, it's actually a `Num a => a`. Haskell does not have a way to know that `Int` is the only `a` that satisfies `(Num a, Lift a) => a`, so it needs to be told this explicitly. For example, if I create in another module the following instance:

```
instance Num String where
    ...
```

Then `declare' 1` becomes ambiguous, and could reasonably result in either `"String:..."` or `"Int:..."`. Haskell can't know at compile time that I won't do this, so we have a problem.